# Highcharts line chart time series showing integer as x axis even though i specified date format

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using Highcharts on React, and am trying to display a time series on a line chart. I have searched code examples and have tried out many different ways but the X-axis keeps on showing dates in milliseconds. This is despite specifying the X-axis format in the chart options, and also trying different ways to create a date object eg. Date.UTC, new Date(2023,1,1) etc.

[image]

```
const LineChart = ({data}: { data: PriceType[] }) => {

    const prices = [
        [Date.UTC(2023, 0, 1), 10],
        [Date.UTC(2023, 1, 1), 15],
        [Date.UTC(2023, 2, 1), 20],
        // Add more data points here
    ]

    const getOptions = (type: string) => ({
        chart: {
            type,
            width: 700,
            height: 300,
        },
        title: {
            text: "chart",
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Values',
            },
        },
        XAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },

        series: [
            {
                data: prices,
            }
        ],

    });

    return (
        <div>
            <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={getOptions('line')}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LineChart;
```

Comment: It should be `xAxis`, not upper-case `X`.